# Is it possible to use "Quick Export as PNG" in a Photoshop action?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

This function seems particularly buggy in PS CC. Insert Menu Item calls it "Quick Export as Gif" and only imports it as "Select  Menu Item".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to run a script from an action.
With an image open

Start a new action,call it "save as PNG".
Press record on the actions menu.
Run the script from the file menu.
Press "stop" on the actions menu

Please note: The script referenced by the action, needs to be in the same place for the action to work ach time - so make a copy before hand or make the action look for it in the scripts folder.

I've not looked at the script in question, so where it'll save, the file and under what name is anyone's guess. But the principle is sound.